# Changing collation on schema

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, collation

I have access to a database where the `collation` is set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. And of course I want it to be `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`. Now the problem is just that there already exists tables in an other schema that I don't want to mess with. So first of, can I change the `Collation` of my own schema? And secondly, is that a ok way to do this? or is there any other, better way to deal with the situation?

Comment: See http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3221/how-to-change-the-collation-of-a-sql-server-column/. You will have to drop and recreate indexes etc.

Comment: But, I don't have any data yet, nor any tables. So would just like to change the collation on the schema that I have, or since it's empty, drop it and create a new schema with the correct collation.

Comment: Or is it just not possible to set the collation on a schema?

Comment: Then you can for example only change default database collation and then create the schema. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx. Changing default database collation does not affect existing objects in the database.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already failed at that:
`The object 'AVCON_1227776622_ACCES_000' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation` and a bunch of those...

Comment: So what about specifying collation for every column separately and explicitly? I do not think there is anything like default collation for a schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default colation cannot be specified per SQL Server database schema. The default collation can be specified per SQL Server database or per SQL Server instance only.

Setting default collation for SQL Server database does not change collation of existing database objects. It only specifies what collation is to be used by default when creating new database objects. So when you need to create multiple database objects with a specific collation you can beforehand change default database collation - it will not change the existing objects.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase COLLATE French_CI_AS ;
```

However changing default database collation becomes tricky when you have schema-bound objects that depend on the collation of the database. Then you recieve following error:

`The object 'XY' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it.`

In that case it is better to specify collation for every column separately and explicitly like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
 (PrimaryKey   int PRIMARY KEY,
  CharCol      varchar(10) COLLATE French_CI_AS NOT NULL
 );
```